# Plot normal distribution in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to plot the comun distribution of two normal distributed variables.

The code below plots one normal distributed variable. What would the code be for plotting two normal distributed variables?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you define the 'comun' distribution?

matplotlib3d has many examples that may help you do what you need

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a [Multivariate Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). This is implemented in scipy as [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html). It's important to remember that you are passing a covariance matrix to the function. So to keep things simple keep the off diagonal elements as zero:

```
[X variance ,     0    ]
[     0     ,Y Variance]
```

Here is an example using this function and generating a 3D plot of the resulting distribution. I add the colormap to make seeing the curves easier but feel free to remove it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Parameters to set
mu_x = 0
variance_x = 3

mu_y = 0
variance_y = 15

#Create grid and multivariate normal
x = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X; pos[:, :, 1] = Y
rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[variance_x, 0], [0, variance_y]])

#Make a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos),cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

Giving you this plot:
[image]

## Edit the method used below was deprecated in Matplotlib v2.2 and removed in v3.1

<strike>A simpler version is available through [matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal)
It takes the following arguments so you don't need to worry about matrices
`matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, sigmax=1.0, sigmay=1.0, mux=0.0, muy=0.0, sigmaxy=0.0)`
 Here X, and Y are again the result of a meshgrid so using this to recreate the above plot:</strike>

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Parameters to set
mu_x = 0
sigma_x = np.sqrt(3)

mu_y = 0
sigma_y = np.sqrt(15)

#Create grid and multivariate normal
x = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = bivariate_normal(X,Y,sigma_x,sigma_y,mu_x,mu_y)

#Make a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cmap='viridis',linewidth=0)
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: It should be `from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal`.

Comment: It seems like `bivariate_normal` will eventually be removed though: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The bivariate_normal function was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 and will be removed in 3.1.`

Comment: Let's say that the Gaussian function is my likelihood, but I want to multiply it by its associated prior (Pa). How can I include Pa in this code?

Answer (score 7):

The following adaption to @Ianhi's code above returns a contour plot version of the 3D plot above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal




#Parameters to set
mu_x = 0
variance_x = 3

mu_y = 0
variance_y = 15

x = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,500)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

pos = np.array([X.flatten(),Y.flatten()]).T



rv = multivariate_normal([mu_x, mu_y], [[variance_x, 0], [0, variance_y]])


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax0.contour(X, Y, rv.pdf(pos).reshape(500,500))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are great, I wanted to achieve similar results while also illustrating the distribution with a scatter plot of the sample.

More details can be found here: [Python 3d plot of multivariate gaussian distribution](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/python/dataviz/python-3d-scatter-and-density/)

The results looks like:

[image: Bivariate gaussian distribution and sample plot]

And is generated using the following code:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


# Sample parameters
mu = np.array([0, 0])
sigma = np.array([[0.7, 0.2], [0.2, 0.3]])
rv = multivariate_normal(mu, sigma)
sample = rv.rvs(500)

# Bounds parameters
x_abs = 2.5
y_abs = 2.5
x_grid, y_grid = np.mgrid[-x_abs:x_abs:.02, -y_abs:y_abs:.02]

pos = np.empty(x_grid.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = x_grid
pos[:, :, 1] = y_grid

levels = np.linspace(0, 1, 40)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Removes the grey panes in 3d plots
ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

# The heatmap
ax.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, 0.1 * rv.pdf(pos),
            zdir='z', levels=0.1 * levels, alpha=0.9)

# The wireframe
ax.plot_wireframe(x_grid, y_grid, rv.pdf(
    pos), rstride=10, cstride=10, color='k')

# The scatter. Note that the altitude is defined based on the pdf of the
# random variable
ax.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1], 1.05 * rv.pdf(sample), c='k')

ax.legend()
ax.set_title("Gaussian sample and pdf")
ax.set_xlim3d(-x_abs, x_abs)
ax.set_ylim3d(-y_abs, y_abs)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

plt.show()
```