# 3D Probability Density Plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability-distribution

I am working on a data set consisting of 'pulse length' values and 5 or 6 'voltage values' corresponding to each of the pulse lengths. The first value is pulse length followed by voltages. Find the table below.

15  -56V    -47V    -53V    -50V    -50V

---

16  -49V    -46V    -52V    -47V    -50V

---

17  -50V    -51V    -47V    -50V    -49V

---

18  -50V    -51V    -48V    -48V    -45V

---

19  -49V    -51V    -45V    -47V    -52V

---

20  -45V    -47V    -50V    -47V    -54V

---

21  -46V    -52V    -52V    -49V    -54V

---

22  -53V    -51V    -53V    -56V    -52V

---

23  -52V    -45V    -51V    -56V    -53V

---

24  -51V    -52V    -54V    -58V    -52V

---

25  -56V    -53V    -57V    -55V    -53V

---

26  -53V    -52V    -55V    -52V

---

27  -54V    -49V    -56V    -54V

---

28  -52V    -52V    -57V    -56V    -53V

---

29  -63V    -60V    -54V    -58V    -61V

---

30  -59V    -70V    -61V

---

I want the X and Y axis to be pulse length and voltage and I want the Z axis to be its probability distribution.  I have a 2D plot for the same using the set of 'voltage values' and its probability.
[image]
In the picture, the red graph corresponds to one pulse length and green graph corresponds to another pulse length. I tried doing the 3D plot the same way using an example of multivariate normal distribution example from stack overflow ([Plot normal distribution in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698277/plot-normal-distribution-in-3d)). Since I have very little experience with 3D plots, I am unable to plot multiple surface plots on the same surface with different Y axis 'pulse length' values. The code that I tried is given below.

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

 #Parameters to set
 mu_x = -48.8
 sigma_x = np.sqrt(6.5)

 mu_y = 0
 sigma_y = np.sqrt(16)

 #Create grid and multivariate normal
 x = range(-100,0)
 y = range(15,30)
 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
 Z = bivariate_normal(X,Y,sigma_x,sigma_y,mu_x,mu_y)


 #Make a 3D plot
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
 ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cmap='Reds',linewidth=0, antialiased=True, 
 zorder = 0.5)

 ax.set_xlabel('Voltage')
 ax.set_ylabel('Pulse Length')
 ax.set_zlabel('Normal Distribution')
 plt.show()
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me do the same for multiple pulse lengths.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of plot you want to achieve exactly but from what I understood, you want something like the below figure. I am putting only the relevant/modified code below. It's also not clear what variable is your pulse length. Since you have many pulse lengths, you can put the function to define `mu_x`, 'mu_y', `Z` in a `for` loop and plot several 3d surfaces.

```
# Create grid and multivariate normal
x = np.linspace(-100, 0, 200) # Create a mesh of 200 x-points
y = np.linspace(-30, 30, 200) # Create a mesh of 200 y-points

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = bivariate_normal(X,Y,sigma_x,sigma_y,mu_x,mu_y)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X,Y,sigma_x,sigma_y,mu_x-20,mu_y+10)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cmap='Reds',linewidth=0, antialiased=True, zorder = 0.5)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2,cmap='Blues',linewidth=0, alpha=0.5, antialiased=True, zorder = 0.5)
```

**Output**

[image]