# ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing - Contour plot in Python

Tags: contour, gaussian, probability-density

I am trying to plot density estimates using a contour plot and getting the following error.

```
A = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 2))
#mean = np.mean(x)
#cov = np.cov(x)
mean = np.array([0.5, 0.1])
cov = np.array([[0.1, 0.0], [0.0, 1.5,]])

B = multivariate_normal.pdf(A, mean=mean, cov=cov)


# visualize
contours = plt.contour(A, B, linewidths=2)
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True,  fontsize=12)
#plt.plot(x, y)
plt.colorbar();
```

Comment: You need to use `meshgrid`. The second answer of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698277/plot-normal-distribution-in-3d) has an implementation

Answer (score 5):

For someone in future that has this problem in seaborn, I discovered that my data had some extreme outliers, meaning there was effectively no density to plot as 99% of the samples were around the origin. Using the 'clip' functionality in kdeplot worked to reduce the axis and thus plot the actual levels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).